# Dynamic Form How To Process Saved Posted Values

Tags: dynamic-visualforce, apex

I fear this is a path well trod, littered with the bodies of dead developers. Upvote me if you too have wasted time on this.

So I've got a page rendered programmatically by adding textboxes, labels and checkbox Apex Components to a dynamic control, largely based on the article below and other advice on this forum (thanks for that). https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_components_implementation.htm):

The SF example suggests the controllers Save method might be invoked to enact a Save implying the data from the controls will be processed in the Save method. Unfortunately no code showing the Save method is present leaving a lot to be guessed at.

Is it even possible to get the form controls values in the Save method?

The design paradigm seems to be to bind to properties of controls to (properties of) public variables exposed by the controller.

Its not clear whether 2-way binding only works on sObjects and not to wrappers.

As soon as the Save method is entered if 2-way binding worked, the controllers member variables have the data already, there's no need to muck about with the control tree; it's probably not accessible anyhow and not needed.

So what if you've produced a control tree dynamically and given the controls values - what then - how do you get at their values when the form is posted back. They are not bound to member variables so the state is in the controls.

Can this even be done. I'm thinking I have to write a client-side JS application now and use AJAX to post back data to an action method.

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic visualforce components also work with wrapper objects and you can have complete control for 2 way binding of data

Here is a simple example doing that

```
public with sharing Class Controller {
List<WrappedRecord> myRecords = new List<WrappedRecords>();

... //Code to query and build myRecords and any other methods not needed for demo

public Class WrappedRecord {
public Record__c detail { get; set; }
public List<WrappedRecords> children { get; set; }

public WrappedRecord(Record__c theRecord) {
    this.detail = theRecord;
    this.children = new List<WrappedRecord>();
}
}

public Component.Apex.OutputPanel getThePanel(){
Component.Apex.OutputPanel outPanel = new Component.Apex.OutputPanel();
for(Integer i=0; i<myRecords.size(); i++) {
outPanel.childComponents.add( addChildComponents(myRecords, 0, 'myRecords') );
}
return outPanel;
}

private Component.Apex.OutputPanel addChildComponents(List<WrappedRecords> wrappers, Integer level, String accessString) {
accessString = accessString + '[' + level + ']';
Component.Apex.OutputPanel outPanel = new Component.Apex.OutputPanel();
{
    Component.Apex.InputText inTxt = new Component.Apex.InputText( value = wrappers.detail.Name );
    inTxt.expressions.value = '{!' + accessString + '}';
    outPanel.childComponents.add( inTxt );
}
outPanel.childComponents.add( addChildComponents( wrappers.children, level+1, accessString + 'children') );

return outPanel;
 }
}
```

|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

```
   <apex:page controller=”Controller”>
<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue=”{!thePanel}”/>
  </apex:page>
```